# Concatenate value via np.concatenate python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Any help to get me started is appreciated. I have a large data frame and this is a small example where I am trying to concatenate arrays in the data frame but it is extremely slow for large data (many rows and columns).

This is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Define a dictionary containing students data 
data = {#'Name': ['Ankit', 'Amit'], 
                'Val': [np.zeros(2)],
                'Val1':[np.ones(2)],
                'Val2':[np.ones(2)]
} 
  
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Val','Val1','Val2']) 

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    prev = np.zeros((1,1,2))
    for r in row:
        prev = np.concatenate((prev, [[r.tolist()]]))
X=np.delete(prev, 0,axis=0).reshape(df.shape[0],df.shape[1],2)
```

I have searched and some post suggest to use pandas apply but I don't know how to do it. Just wondering if anyone could share a better way to do it so that I can started. Thank you.

Edit:
Updated the answer based on the suggested by @StupidWolf. Thank you!

```
def format(df):
    result = []
    for idx in df.index:
        print(idx)
        X=np.vstack(df.to_numpy()[idx])
        print(X)
        result.append(X)
    return result

    result = format(df)
    nsamples, nx, ny = result.shape
    print(nsamples,nx,ny)
```

When I print X, I get the expected output and shape but when I add it to the list, I am unable to see the shape. The shape is important for me as I need to change the dimensional. Thank you.

Comment: i am a bit confused about what you are trying to do. In this example, you get the end result by doing, ```np.vstack(df.to_numpy()[0])```

Comment: Are you trying to stack vertically all the columns for each row? So that for every index, you have a 3x2 array ?

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much. Yes, stacking works awesome. It only works for one row. In order to do it for the whole data frame, do I loop through and change the j value. np.vstack(s_train.to_numpy()[j])

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to stack the columns for every row entry, you can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val0':[np.random.randint(0,5,2) for i in range(3)],
'Val1':[np.random.randint(0,5,2) for i in range(3)],
'Val2':[np.random.randint(0,5,2) for i in range(3)]})
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
     Val0    Val1    Val2
0  [2, 1]  [0, 1]  [1, 0]
1  [0, 3]  [0, 0]  [3, 4]
2  [2, 2]  [3, 3]  [2, 0]
```

You can stack very row like this:

```
[np.vstack(i) for i in df.to_numpy()]
```

To see the shape you need to make this list a np.array:

```
res = np.array([np.vstack(i) for i in df.to_numpy()])
res.shape
(3, 3, 2)
```

Gives you a list, length of your rows:

```
[array([[2, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 0]]),
 array([[0, 3],
        [0, 0],
        [3, 4]]),
 array([[2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [2, 0]])]
```

Or if you are familiar with pandas:

```
res = df.apply(lambda i:np.vstack(i),axis=1)
```

It's organised into a series and very element has the shape you need:

```
res[0]
 
array([[2, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])

res[1]
 
array([[0, 3],
       [0, 0],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: Thank you @StupidWolf. I am unable to post code below and so, I have added an update on the question in the Edit section. I get the expected output for each row when I print X but I don't know which container to add so that I can change the shape.

Comment: Hi @zizi, it seems like you have a different question and it has nothing to do with your original question.SO is meant as a question and answer repository, not for you to troubleshoot your code and answer your queries like this. Stop moving the goal post

Comment: I will help you this time around, but please refrain from this in the future or define your question properly right from the start.

Comment: I converted it to np.array and it works. Sorry, if it wasn't clear. I accepted the answer by clicking the accepted as it answered the question. However, I didn't post to an new post mainly because based on experience, I am asked to post under the same thread and thus, I posted here. Sorry if it didn't look like that. Thank you